# Adding Parse Object to intent

Tags: android, android-intent, parse-platform

So I have a ParseQueryAdapter and I'm trying to use the share intent method. I got it to where the share intent functions but it only sends the extra text not the parse object. I tried using Parse Query but that didn't work. Anybody with an idea on how to retrieve the parse object. Here is my code below:

```
//Set share button to
    ImageButton shareButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById (R.id.shareButton);
    shareButton.setClickable (true);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Ads");
            try {
                query.get ("title").toString ();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
            bundle.get ("title");

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent (getContext (), ContentFeed.class);
            sendIntent.setAction (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.putExtras (bundle);
            sendIntent.setType ("text/plain");
            getContext ().startActivity (Intent.createChooser (sendIntent, getContext ().getText (R.string.send_to)));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to get the ParseObject ID, pass it to the intent and then upon receiving the ParseObject ID, get it from the Parse database.

Comment: I'm trying to use ParseObject but how can I pass it to the intent?

Comment: Try to get the id of the parse object , that's all and than set it as an extra field and get it when you receive the intent

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
bundle.get ("title");
```

you just get a new bundle, why using get?

maybe something like

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
 try {
     bundle.putCharSequence("title", query.get ("title").toString ());
 } catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace ();
 }
```

Comment: It didn't work, the Intent on shows the EXTRA_TEXT string not the string from the title.

Comment: @user3900101 so what do you really want to pass through intent? `ParseObject po = query.get("title");` ?

Comment: I want the string from the item in the ListActivity to be passed through intent. So I need to figure out how to pass the string loaded in the item from parse to the intent as a text.

Comment: If you only need to send one string, replace `"This is my text to send."` in your code with a variable of the string from the title (state previously like `str = query.get ("title").toString ();`). Do you mean this?

Comment: that looks how I want to get the text in the item, but when I click the button and select a medium (Facebook) there's no text from the item.

Answer (score 0):

Although @Kiloreux's solution is correct in most cases sometimes you have already called the data you need and don't want to wastefully make another call, in which case:

Here is a wrapper for simple Parse Objects which enable it to be passed in an intent [ParseProxyObject](https://gist.github.com/jamiechapman/5375115).

Usage:

```
// --- Sending ---
ParseProxyObject ppo = new ParseProxyObject(myParseObject);

Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("parseObject", ppo);

// --- Receiving ---
Intent intent = getIntent();
ParseProxyObject ppo = (ParseProxyObject)intent.getSerializableExtra("parseObject");
Log.v("Test", String.format("Proxy object name: %s", ppo.getString("name")));
```

Thanks to Jamie Chapman for making it available.